How to select a reference level for categorical variables using Scikit-Learn?
I'm trying to convert a code from SAS to Python which trains a GLM. For that, I'm using the hpgenselect with the CLASS word to deal with categorical variables. In SAS I can select the reference level for any categorical variable that the model needs. The reference level is the category which will receive the value 0, and that will be the reference which the other variables are being compared.
I've searched but I didn't find an analogous way to do this in Scikit-Learn. Is there any way to select a reference in scikit-learn or in other Python library?

It might be best to show a simple example of how this encoding would work, on something that looks like your data.

Use onehotencoder and the manual option. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html
